# Expand relative path wrt containing file

Tags: vim

I am reading a config file, `foo.yml` with Vimscript. This file contains a parameter that is the relative path to a directory. This `path` is relative to the `foo.yml` file, not my current working directory.

I need to expand this relative path to an absolute path.

I have tried using `fnamemodify(path, ':p')` and `expand(path)` without luck. I think these functions seem to get confused because from the current working directory the relative path is invalid. So it keeps the path as is.

Is there a way to make Vim use the `foo.yml` as the point-of-reference when resolving relative paths? Or any other function that can do the same?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to expand relative to the file's directory, it's easiest to temporarily `:cd` into that directory. Here's some sample code that does this for the current file (`%`); you have to adapt this to work with a passed filespec.

```
if expand('%:h') !=# '.'
    " Need to change into the file's directory first to get glob results
    " relative to the file.
    let l:save_cwd = getcwd()
    let l:chdirCommand = (haslocaldir() ? 'lchdir!' : 'chdir!')
    execute l:chdirCommand '%:p:h'
endif
try
    " Get the full path to a:filespec, relative to the current file's directory.
    let l:absoluteFilespec = fnamemodify(a:filespec, ':p')
finally
    if exists('l:save_cwd')
        execute l:chdirCommand fnameescape(l:save_cwd)
    endif
endtry
```

Comment: Good answer! This gets the job done. Also good tip to use it inside try-catch.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
:let dir = expand('%:p:h')
:let absolute_path = dir . '/' . path
```

You will have to work harder if you want it to work on Windows, too.

```
:help expand()
:help filename-modifiers
:help file-functions
```

Comment: Nice try, but wouldn't work if the `path` could be relative to it's children.

Comment: Please clarify, or give an example.  It seems to me that I have answered the question as asked, but I guess I am missing something.  "I am reading a config file, foo.yml ... This path is relative to the foo.yml file."  Does `expand('%:p:h')` not give the directory of foo.yml, or is that not what you mean by "relative to the foo.yml file"?

Comment: Your answer is good. But if path is relative, say `a/b/c/d` wrt to the directory in which `foo.yml` is, then it doesn't work. Anyway, Thanks for your help, but I've implemented with wrapping the code with `lcd` and restoring as suggested by @Ingo.

Comment: I still do not see an example.  If foo.xml is in the directory /x/y/z/ and path is a/b/c/d, then my absolute_path comes out as /x/y/z/a/b/c/d.  Is that not what you want?